# Terraform script to build and run Dataflow Flex template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-dataflow, terraform-provider-gcp

Need to convert these 2 gcloud commands to build and run dataflow jobs using Terraform.

```
  gcloud dataflow flex-template build ${TEMPLATE_PATH} \
       --image-gcr-path "${TARGET_GCR_IMAGE}" \
       --sdk-language "JAVA" \
       --flex-template-base-image ${BASE_CONTAINER_IMAGE} \
       --metadata-file "/Users/b.j/g/codebase/g-dataflow/pubsub-lite/src/main/resources/g_pubsublite_to_gcs_metadata.json" \
       --jar "/Users/b.j/g/codebase/g-dataflow/pubsub-lite/target/debian/pubsub-lite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-uber.jar" \
       --env FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS="com.in.g.gr.dataflow.PubSubLiteToGCS"



  gcloud dataflow flex-template run "pub-sub-lite-flex-`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`" \
    --template-file-gcs-location=$TEMPLATE_FILE_LOCATION \
    --parameters=subscription=$SUBSCRIPTION,output=$OUTPUT_DIR,windowSize=$WINDOW_SIZE_IN_SECS,partitionLevel=$PARTITION_LEVEL,numOfShards=$NUM_SHARDS \
    --region=$REGION \
    --worker-region=$WORKER_REGION \
    --staging-location=$STAGING_LOCATION \
    --subnetwork=$SUBNETWORK \
    --network=$NETWORK
```

I've tried using the resource `google_dataflow_flex_template_job` from which i can run the dataflow job using the stored dataflow template(2nd gcloud command), now I need to create the template and docker image as per my 1st gcloud command using terraform ?
Any inputs on this ?? And whats the best way to pass the jars used in the 1st gcloud command (placing it in GCS bucket) ?

Comment: Hey Sanjay, I've been looking for an answer to this question too, I can see you've asked on StackOverflow, raised a GitHub Issue and posted in the Terrafrom SubReddit but not gotten an answer on any, what did you do in the end?

Answer (score -1):

> And whats the best way to pass the jars used in the 1st gcloud command (placing it in GCS bucket)?

There is no need to manually store these jar files in GCS. The `gcloud dataflow flex-template build` command will build a docker container image including all the required jar files and upload the image to the container registry. This image (+ the metadata file) is the only thing needed to run the template.

> now I need to create the template and docker image as per my 1st gcloud command using terraform ?

AFAIK there is no special terraform module to build a flex template. I'd try using the [terraform-google-gcloud](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google/latest) module, which can execute an arbitrary gcloud command, to run `gcloud dataflow flex-template build`.

If you build your project using Maven, another option is using jib-maven-plugin to build and upload the container image instead of using `gcloud dataflow flex-template build`. See [these build instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/v2/datastream-to-bigquery#building-template) for an example. You'll still need to upload the json image spec ("Creating Image Spec" section in the instructions) somehow, e.g. using the `gsutil` command or maybe using terraform's `google_storage_bucket_object`, so I think this approach is more complicated.